# Why synchronized method doesn't work in my case (or rather what is wrong with my assumption)?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I have this code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

interface Counter {

    public void increment();

    public void decrement();

    public int value();

}

class SynchronizedCounter implements Counter {

    private int c = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }

}

class UnsynchronizedCounter implements Counter {

    private int c = 0;

    @Override
    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    @Override
    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    @Override
    public int value() {
        return c;
    }

}

public class TestProjectApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AtomicLong unsynchronizedErrors = new AtomicLong();
        AtomicLong synchronizedErrors = new AtomicLong();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Counter c = new UnsynchronizedCounter();
            (new Thread(() -> {
                c.increment();
            })).start();

            (new Thread(() -> {
                if (c.value() != 1) {
                    unsynchronizedErrors.incrementAndGet();
                }
            })).start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Counter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
            (new Thread(() -> {
                c.increment();
            })).start();

            (new Thread(() -> {
                if (c.value() != 1) {
                    synchronizedErrors.incrementAndGet();
                }
            })).start();
        }

        System.out.println("Unsynchronized errors: " + unsynchronizedErrors);
        System.out.println("Synchronized errors: " + synchronizedErrors);

    }

}
```

The result of execution of my program is:

```
Unsynchronized errors: 83
Synchronized errors: 26
```

I understand why there are unsynchronized errors but I don't understand why I've got synchronized errors.

My assumption is that in the second loop the thread which increment number of synchronized errors is obligated to wait until the thread which use SynchronizedCounter::increment() method. What's wrong with the way I think?

### Edit:

It seems that there is no need to make those method synchronized but it's enough to use Thread::join() method in second thread. But still I don't understand why it haven't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. `synchronized` guarantees that the executions of your methods will not be interleaved, and that they will have **an** ordering. You expect the threads to run in a specific order, but you are not enforcing the order in any way.

In your second loop, you expect the threads to reach the execution of the synchronized methods in the order in which the threads are created. But what can happen in the loop body

```
    Counter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
    (new Thread(() -> {
        c.increment();
    })).start();

    (new Thread(() -> {
        if (c.value() != 1) {
            synchronizedErrors.incrementAndGet();
        }
    })).start();
```

is that the `Thread` that you created **second** (the `synchronizedErrors` checker) runs before the **first** one (the one that does the incrementing). You classify this as an error, but no error has happened.

### edit

The best way to fix this is to `join` all threads that do incrementing/decrementing before querying the state of the counter.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it better to use join() method instead of introducing a flag? Here is my new code which take advantage of synchronization and joining: http://pastebin.com/8CipmzLY.

Comment: Yes, `join` is the simplest solution, you caught me in between edits.